# The meaning of "v. Prendre le seum"

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

In the French song "On fleek", Eva said "T'as pris le seum et tu t'agites" so what's the meaning of this sentence and what's the difference between "v.avoir + le seum" & "v.prendre + le seum"?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

*Le seum* is a slang word for a grudge, a feeling of resentment, of being gutted.

*Avoir le seum*  means to have this feeling, and *prendre le seum* is just the "action" of developing this feeling.

Answer (score 0):

"avoir le seum" means "to be mad" or "to be angry".
"prendre le seum" means "to get mad" or "to get angry".

"T'as pris le seum et tu t'agites" means "You got angry and you're getting all worked up."